# How do you submit a form using <a>

Tags: html, forms, href

I tried the suggestion such as submit();, but it doesn't work for me...  Can someone help.

```
 <section class="section_bkg" id="login">
    <form action="login.php" method="post" id="submit_login">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label class="block" for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="block" for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="document.form['submit_login'].submit();">Log in</a></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: The way it's written now - it will submit the form to login.php using POST. why do you think it doesn't work ?

Comment: just edit it to <a></a>, the <input> method works just find.. but I need to use <a> because the css for buttons doesn't work well with <input>

Answer (score 2):

First give the form an id attribute so you can reference it:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="myform">
```

Now you can do a Javascript-submit, using the *onclick* event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit();">Click to submit the form</a>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me... i am using localhost.. not sure if that has anything to do with it.  I update the script above.

Comment: @LapMingLee I noticed you have a typo -- make sure it's **document.forms** (not *form*).  It shouldn't matter about localhost.  Do you have a file at *login.php* to handle the post?

Comment: yeah i have login.php. everything works fine if I use <input>

Answer (score 0):

Building on @dbaseman's answer. If you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to submit the form this should help.

**Html**

```
<a href="#" id="MySubmitButton" name="MySubmitButton">Click to save</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
// submit
$('#MySubmitButton').click(function () {
    $('form').submit();
    return false;
});

// OR - bypassing any unbotrusive validation
$('#MySubmitButton').click(function () {
    $('form')[0].submit();
    return false;
});

// using the enter key to submit the form
$('#password, #email').keypress(function (event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == 13) {
        $('form').submit();

        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript provides the form object that contains the submit() method. Use the ‘id’ of the form to get the form object. For example, if the name of your form is ‘myform’, the JavaScript code for the submit call is:

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

But, how to identify a form? Give an id attribute in the form tag

```
<form id='myform' action='handle-data.php'>
```

Here is the code to submit a form when a hyperlink is clicked:

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="handle-data.php">
Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
<a href="javascript: submitform()">Search</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Answer

```
 <form action="login.php" method="post" id="myform" name="myform">
 </form>
 <a href="javascript:document.myform.submit();">Click to submit the form</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick=
 "document.getElementById('submit_login').submit(); return false">Log in</a>
```

But it’s really more useable and more accessible to use a submit button, so it is better to fix whatever issues you have with styling, rather than implement basic functionality this way.